# rails exception caught by rescue_from but still causing internal server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

I am migrating a rails application which uses a mySQL database backend and requires users to login to the database.  When the user login is invalid, the mySQL driver raises the expected ActiveRecord::JDBCError exception.  I am catching this exception via 'rescue_from' in the ApplicationController where I attempt to redirect to another page.  It looks as though the exception is caught and the redirect is occurring, however the "Internal Server Error" page is displayed instead of the page that I am attempting to redirect to.  I am simply testing this with the WEBrick server.

Here are the relevant details:

Ruby version:
jruby 1.7.13 (1.9.3p392) 2014-06-24 43f133c on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_55-mockbuild_2014_04_09_11_51-b00 [linux-amd64]

Rails version:
Rails 4.1.1

application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::JDBCError do |exception|
    redirect_to :controller=>"/account", :action =>"logout
  end

end
```

The 'logout' method is simply

```
def logout
   session['user'] = nil
end
```

Server command line output:

```
Started POST "/login" for 10.196.145.220 at 2014-08-27 10:57:12 -0700
Processing by AccountController#login as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9uE89hmHsmA94u+ItzNldTeEa8nWyNmLuxoifhTN7eY=", "user_login"=>"", "user_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Login"}
Redirected to http://server-1:3000/logout
Completed 302 Found in 46ms
[2014-08-27 10:57:12] ERROR ActiveRecord::JDBCError: The driver encountered an unknown error: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'server.test.org' (using password: NO)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.13/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.9/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:23:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.13/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.9/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:68:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.13/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.9/lib/arjdbc/mysql/adapter.rb:658:in `initialize'
....
```